# Issue with dropdown navigation menu sliding onced opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just updated my site with a new navigation menu and when I open the menu with the hamburger icon then rollover any of my drop down menu options the entire menu slides down when the drop down opens and then repositions in the correct spot. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Link: [aaie.net](http://aaie.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `li` elements has a `display: inline-block` set.

To fix that, add this `vertical-align: top;` to that `li` element.

It will now look like this:

```
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
  background-color: transparent;
  /* display: block; */
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```